# ASP.NET/C# chart form dropdown only populates on last option, chart only appears if text in second textbox

Tags: javascript, c#, mysql, asp.net, html

So I have a chart form that allows the user to select a station (A, B, C, or D) from a dropdown, then allows them to pick a unit (1, 2 or 3) from another dropdown which is dynamically populated based on the station selection, for example station D only has and displays unit 2. The other three stations, A, B and C, display units 1, 2 and 3, but only allow the user to pick unit 1. In other words the unit dropdown only populates correctly on station D.

Additionally there are two textboxes which allow the user to select a "From" and "To" date, these dates are then displayed in an asp label above an asp column chart with this data, both of which appear upon the "Chart" button being clicked. However the label and chart only successfully coexist if there is no text in the "From" textbox. If there is any text in the "From" textbox, only the label is displayed.

Here is the **MainForm.aspx** code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MainForm.aspx.cs" Inherits="ChartApplication.MainForm" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" Namespace="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting" TagPrefix="asp" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type ="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#TextBoxFrom').datepicker({
                showOn: 'both',
                numberOfMonths: 1,
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true
            });
            $('#TextBoxTo').datepicker({
                showOn: 'both',
                numberOfMonths: 1,
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true
            });
        }
    )</script>



</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <table  style="font-family:Calibri; border:1px solid black";>
         <tr >
            <td>
                Select Station:
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddStation" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
            </td>
             <td>Select Unit:
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddUnit" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
             </td> 
             <td> From:
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxFrom"  runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
             </td>
            <td> To:
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxTo" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td></td></tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
             <th colspan="2">
               <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Chart" Width="92px" />
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr><td></td></tr>
        <tr class="h1">     
          <th colspan="3">  <asp:Label ID="chartTitle" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label> </th>
        </tr>
       <tr><td><b>MW</b></td></tr> 
        <tr>
             <td colspan="4">       
                <asp:Chart ID="ColumnChart" runat="server" Height="250px" Width="500px">
                    <Series>
                        <asp:Series Name="Series1" ChartType="Column" ChartArea="MainArea" IsValueShownAsLabel="true"></asp:Series>
                    </Series>
                    <ChartAreas>
                        <asp:ChartArea Name="MainArea" Area3DStyle-Enable3D="false"></asp:ChartArea>
                    </ChartAreas>
                </asp:Chart>
             </td>
        </tr>
       <tr><th colspan="3">Date</th></tr>
    </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and the **MainForm.aspx.cs** code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

namespace ChartApplication
{
    public partial class MainForm : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                populateStation();
            }
            else
            {
                populateUnits();
            }
        }

       /* void setTitle()
        {
            chartTitle.Text = "From: " + TextBoxFrom.Text + " To: " + TextBoxTo.Text;
        }*/



        void getChartData()
        {
           // chartTitle.Text = "From: " + TextBoxFrom.Text + " To: " + TextBoxTo.Text;
            String ConString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cs"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConString))
            {
                String SQLText = "select AvailDate,MW from MWAvailability2 where UnitName = @UnitName and Station = @StationName and AvailDate between @AvailFrom and @AvailTo";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SQLText, connection);
                connection.Open();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UnitName", ddUnit.SelectedValue);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StationName", ddStation.SelectedValue);
                if (TextBoxFrom.Text.Length > 0)
                    {
                       // chartTitle.Text = "From: " + TextBoxFrom.Text + " To: " + TextBoxTo.Text;    
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AvailFrom", TextBoxFrom.Text);
                    }
                else
                    {
                      //  chartTitle.Text = "From: 01/01/1900 " + " To: " + TextBoxTo.Text;    
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AvailFrom", "01-01-1900");
                    }
                if (TextBoxTo.Text.Length > 0)
                    {
                      //  chartTitle.Text = "From: " + TextBoxFrom.Text + " To: " + TextBoxTo.Text;    
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AvailTo", TextBoxTo.Text);
                    }
                else
                    {
                     //   chartTitle.Text = "From: " + TextBoxFrom.Text + " To: 01/01/2050";
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AvailTo", "01-01-2050");
                    }

                if (TextBoxFrom.Text.Length > 0 && TextBoxTo.Text.Length > 0)   // Text in from, text in to
                {
                    chartTitle.Text = "From: " + TextBoxFrom.Text + " To: " + TextBoxTo.Text;
                }
                else if (TextBoxFrom.Text.Length > 0 && TextBoxTo.Text.Length == 0)     // Text in from, no text in to
                {
                    chartTitle.Text = "From: " + TextBoxFrom.Text + " To: 01/01/2050";
                }
                else if (TextBoxFrom.Text.Length == 0 && TextBoxTo.Text.Length > 0)     // No text in from, text in to
                {
                    chartTitle.Text = "From: 01/01/1900 " + " To: " + TextBoxTo.Text;
                }
                else if (TextBoxFrom.Text.Length == 0 && TextBoxTo.Text.Length == 0)     // No text in from, no text in to
                {
                    chartTitle.Text = "From: 01/01/1900 To: 01/01/2050";
                }



                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Series series = ColumnChart.Series["Series1"];
                    if (reader.HasRows)
                    {
                        series.Points.AddXY(reader["AvailDate"].ToString(), reader["MW"]);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("No rows found.");
                    }
                }

            }
        }



        void populateUnits()
        {
            String ConString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cs"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection connectionString = new SqlConnection(ConString))
            {
                String SQLText = "select distinct(UnitName) as UniqueUnits from MWAvailability2 where isnull(@StationName,Station)=Station";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SQLText, connectionString);             // 1) establish cmd 2) open conn 3) reference cmd
                connectionString.Open();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StationName", ddStation.SelectedValue);
                ddUnit.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                ddUnit.DataTextField = "UniqueUnits";
                ddUnit.DataBind(); 


            }
        }

        void populateStation()
        {
            String ConString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cs"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection connectionString = new SqlConnection(ConString))
            {
                String SQLText = "select distinct(Station) as UniqueStations from MWAvailability2";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SQLText, connectionString);
                connectionString.Open();
                ddStation.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                ddStation.DataTextField = "UniqueStations";
                ddStation.DataBind();


            }
        }



        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           // setTitle();
            getChartData();  
        }


    }
}
```

And here is what it looks like upon initial page load:

[ChartApplication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tzupy.png)

According to breakpoints I had set, as well as what the element inspection has shown me, data collection apparently fails in these areas for whatever reason, and my research/googling has been inconclusive. I have tried rewriting this several different ways to no avail.

What I am trying to accomplish is to get the Unit dropdown to populate dynamically based on the Station selection on all four stations, not just on Station D, as well as to get the chart and label to always appear simultaneously  when the "Chart" button is clicked, not just when the "From" textbox is empty.

I understand that this might not be the proper way to ask a question on here or whatever, but I feel that I am at an impasse here. Can anybody offer any sort of advice and/or suggestions and/or help with this? I am happy to provide any additional code/info that is needed that I may have omitted.

Thank you!

Comment: In your parameters, you have it getting the value from the dropdownlists. But when you bind the lists, you're setting the TextFields without setting the ValueFields and SelectedValue is returning null every time.

Comment: That makes sense, but where specifically in my code is this issue?

Comment: `populateUnits` and `populateStation`. `ddUnit.DataValueField = "UniqueUnits"` and then `ddStation.DataValueField = "UniqueStations"`

Comment: So I should replace DataTextField with DataValueField in these methods?

Comment: No, add the valuefield under the textfield

Comment: I tried that, but it still behaves the same